# Where should you put session.save_path?

Tags: php, session

Since the default `/tmp` is usually open to all accounts in a shared host it's generally advised to use `session.save_path` and set a different location.

Is it assumed that a better location is in `/home/username/example_session_tmp/` as long as it's not in `/home/username/public_html/`?

If so, wouldn't that still be vulnerable in case a hacker were able to inject a script in `public_html` and read `../example_session_tmp/`? Or is it the only way and it's generally assumed your site is secured from script injections?

Note: Database session handler is an alternative option but let's assume it's not possible.

Comment: if hacker has access like you describe sessions are the least of your problems.

Comment: @Dagon true, so I guess setting it to `/home/username/example_session_tmp/` is the best way or are there other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a hacker gets a script into your site, there isn't a lot you can do to stop him from snagging sessions.  If your webserver has access to the sessions then that user will.  No matter where you stick it the hacker can find with with a simple call to `session_save_path`.

To sum up:

- Prevent hackers from getting access. Who cares about sessions if your server is wide open? Secure this first.
- Setting the save_path to `~/sessions` *should* prevent other shared hosting users tampering with your sessions. This does not prevent someone who gains access to your webserver from seeing and tampering with sessions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on where `~/sessions` is exactly located?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  `~/` means your home directory on many *nix systems.  It's a shortcut for `/home/username/`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you for putting in `/home/username/example_session_tmp/`.

But,

- If you have only one site per server, you don't need to change the path
- If you want to make shared hosting your solution, moving to a new path is a good idea (you can check for `apache-mpm-itk` or `php5-fpm`)
- If you want to have multiple servers, the easiest way is to put the session in the database, or create a shared folder (nfs, samba) for the sessions files.